# Compound Expressions in a Function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wanted to calculate the power sum S_p(x) = 1^p + 2^p + 3^p + ... + x^p using the code

```
powersum[x_,p_]:=sum=0;For[i=1,i<x,i++,sum=sum+i^p];sum
```

but it seems to output 0 every time. Why does it do that?

Comment: note by the way your sum is one term short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it is preferable to use `Module[]`:

```
 powersum[x_,p_]:=Module[{sum},sum=0;For[i=1,i<x,i++,sum=sum+i^p];sum]
```

or

```
 powersum[x_,p_]:=Module[{sum=0},For[i=1,i<x,i++,sum=sum+i^p];sum]
```

this is essentially the same as wrapping in `()` except `sum` is protected in a local context.

of course for this example you could as well use :

```
 powersum[x_,p_]:=Sum[i^p,{i,1,x-1}]
```

or

```
 powersum[x_, p_] := Range[x - 1]^p // Total
```

Answer (score 2):

As written, Mathematica is parsing your expression like this:

```
 powersum[x_,p_]:=sum=0;  (*Definition ended here*)
 For[i=1,i<x,i++,sum=sum+i^p];
 sum
```

You need to use to wrap your expression in parenthesis to make them all part of the function definition.

```
powersum[x_,p_]:=(sum=0;For[i=1,i<x,i++,sum=sum+i^p];sum)
```